# Finding the probability an equation has real roots.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, quadratics

If $Q$~UNIF$(0,3)$, find the probability that the roots of the equation $g(t)=0$ are real, where $g(t)=4t^2+4Qt+Q+2$.

There was a similar question asked that I looked at, but I am still a little confused.

I know that real roots imply $b^2-4ac \ge 0$. So, we have $a=4, b=4Q,$ and $c=Q+2$.
This gave me:

$$16(Q-2)(Q+1)\ge 0$$
$$Q\ge 2, Q \le -1$$

From here, I'm not sure how to find the probability that the roots are real. $Q\le -1$ isn't defined on $(0,3)$, so we are just looking at $Q\ge 2$? Because it is continuous that means we don't have to distinguish between $\ge$ and $\gt$.

$$P(Q\gt 2)=1-(Q=2)$$
From the CDF of $X$~UNIF$(a,b)$:

$$F(x:a,b) =\begin{cases}0  & x\le a \\ \frac{x-a}{b-a} & {a\lt x \lt b} \\\ 1 & b\le x \\\end{cases}$$

Is it as simple as plugging in our $x,a,$ and $b$?

$$\frac{2-0}{3-0}=\frac23$$
$$P(Q\ge 2)=1-\frac23=\frac13?$$

I've never encountered finding a probability like this and wanted to be sure I was doing it right.

Comment: $\checkmark$ That's right. $Q$ takes on values that give real roots to the equation in just one third of its uniformly distributed interval, so the required probability is: $^1\!/_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems just as simple as that. The event whose probability you are to find (the equation has real roots) is equivalent to $Q \le -1 \vee Q \ge 2$, and since $P(Q \le -1) = 0$ for the specified distribution, the answer is $P(Q \ge 2)$, which computes to $\frac{1}{3}$ using exactly the method you described.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left.\int_{0}^{3}{1 \over 3}\,{\rm d}Q\,\right\vert_{\,Q\ \geq\ 2}
={1 \over 3}\int_{2}^{3}{\rm d}Q=\color{#66f}{\Large{1 \over 3}}
$$